# Regular expression to remove everything but a specific format

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like this:

> ASD.123.av.234.X_975.dfgdfg

and i wish to round it up to:

> .123.234.

```
 "\\.[0-9]+\\."
```

this represents my current pattern to select the .number. but negative lookahead didnt work for me: `"(?!^\\.[0-9]+\\.)"` do you guys have any ideea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to select the `.number.`

> The lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match

```
(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ9cJ6/1)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \.                       '.'
  )                        end of look-behind
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \.                       '.'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

---

Sample code:

```
String str = "ASD.123.av.234.X_975.dfgdfg";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)\\d+(?=\\.)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
123
234
```

---

What is meaning of your regex pattern?

```
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not: 
    ^                        the beginning of the string
    \.                       '.'
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times )
     \.                       '.'
   )                        end of look-ahead
```

The problem is with `^` that asserts the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (?=.*?\.\d+\..*?).*?(.\d+.).*?
```

You can try this.It employs positive lookahead.

http://regex101.com/r/dK7kR5/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `(\.[0-9]+?\.)(?:.*?\.([0-9]+?\.))+`.

In your output above, you seem to don't want to have `.123..234.` but `.123.234.` This regex accomplishes that. It works without lookaheads.

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rJ4nR1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex below. It would get you all groups of `.number.`. You would have to yoin the nymbers later though.

```
(\.[0-9]+\.)+
```

Try this site for further tests:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html